# Python export dataframe complete column as hyperlinks

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, hyperlink

I am exporting dataframes to excel sheets. Two columns have https addresses. I want to make them these columns hyperlinks. So, when I open the excel sheet, I can simply click the hyperlink.

Present:
[image]

Expected solution:
[image]

My export code:

```
# jobsdf has two columns Job URL, Apply URL that needed to be hyperlinked
with pd.ExcelWriter('My_jobs.xlsx') as writer:
  jobsdf.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='jobs_list')
```

How to hyperlink the two columns Job URL, Apply URL and then export to the excel?

**Update**: after the accepted answer, the excel sheet shows them as a hyperlinks (with no blue underline below)
[image]

Comment: I think this is an Excel issue, not a Pandas one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try editing the cells so that whenever they are converted to excel they are automatically read as a hyperlink. Provided I am correct with the excel formatting, the change would go like this.

```
jobsdf['Job Url'] = jobsdf['Job URL'].map('=HYPERLINK("{}")'.format)
jobsdf['Apply Url'] = jobsdf['Apply URL'].map('=HYPERLINK("{}")'.format)
```

Now all your cells will look like this `=HYPERLINK("https://the.corresponding.link")` and once converted, excel will read them as hyperlinks

Comment: Nice solution. I updated my question to show the answer. Only thing is, I don't see the underlined blue lines for the hyperlink. Can I get these as well?